# ng-selected not working in md-select

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am new bee to angular2 and I have been unable to write code for a dropdown, to be precise I have written all its code everything is working but I am having problem in showing the default value of the

```
<md-select ngModel="selected-preset">
  <md-option *ngFor="let preset of getAllPresets()" ngSelected="preset == getPreset() ? true : null">{{preset | translate}}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

presets gives me a dropdown showing 4 values and one of these values is same as getPreset() function, but still it is not selecting that value by default.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is this angular 2 or angular 1 ?

Comment: it is angular 2

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

You should try this way in angular 2:

```
[selected]="preset == getPreset() ? true : null"
```

instead of

```
ngSelected="preset == getPreset() ? true : null"
```

Will work.

Comment: I tried to do this now it gives following error "unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'selected' since it isn't a known property of 'md-option'"

Comment: Ok, first checkout, angular2 tutorial, you are not using proper syntax `ngModel` it should be `[(ngModel)]`. Second if it's not working then try `change` event. for more detail check here: [md-select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/md-select) So using this event you can bind selected value in `selected-preset`.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest angular material you should use:

```
[(ngModel)]="mySelectedModelValue"
```

In your component define your pre-select:

```
mySelectedModelValue= 'first';
```

Where value is one of the values of your ngFor.
It would appear [selected] or ngSelected isn't supported anymore, even though the docs do still reference the availability of that attribute.